# how do I update python pip to 3.4 on a raspberry pi?

Tags: python, linux, pip

I was trying to install preview-generator and so I typed `pip install preview-generator` and I got this: `ERROR: Package 'preview-generator' requires a different Python: 2.7.16 not in '>= 3.4'` so I tried `pip install -U pip` and it said that `Requirement already up-to-date: pip in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (20.3.4)` so how would I update it?

Edit: I tried `pip3 install preview-generator` and it worked

Comment: pip doesn't replace your python interpreter itself, it only installs packages for that interpreter. If a program needs a newer interpreter, you need to use OS-level tols to do that.

Comment: Which is to say: It's not `pip` that's at version 2.7.6, it's `python` at that version. You might look at whether your distro offers a `python3` package; if it does, `python3 -m pip` may be what you're looking for.

Comment: you likely want to use `pip3` instead.

Comment: @TeejayBruno - you should submit your comment as an answer, because it solved OP's problem.

Comment: Do not edit "Solved" into the title, and do not edit the way your question was solved into its body. You mark a question solved by clicking the checkbox by an answer. If you solved it in a way that isn't given in any answer, add that answer yourself with the "Add An Answer" button (if someone else came up with the answer, you can disclaim credit/reputation by using the "Community Wiki" checkbox).

Comment: (If there's more of an edit war on that point, it'll be time to call in a moderator to lock the question down, disallowing further changes).

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is: don't mess your system's python installation. There might be other modules that depend on that being what it is. Use `pyenv` to manage python versions.

Check https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv

Check this post for a detailed explanation: https://realpython.com/intro-to-pyenv/